# Gradle Error: While Running an Android APP in IDEA

Tags: java, android, gradle

I get an error while I try to Sync Gradle in IDEA.. I tried many things like setting gradle folder in the path variable and also setting the GRADLE_HOME path in System Vraiable but nothings seems to work.

Here is the error:

Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

### Please read the following process output to find out more:

13:20:19.766 [main] DEBUG o.g.l.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonMain - Assuming the daemon was started with following jvm opts: [-XX:MaxPermSize=256m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xmx1024m, -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252, -Duser.country=US, -Duser.language=en, -Duser.variant]
13:20:20.093 [main] DEBUG o.g.l.daemon.server.DaemonServices - Creating daemon context with opts: [-XX:MaxPermSize=256m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xmx1024m, -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252, -Duser.country=US, -Duser.language=en, -Duser.variant]
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

Answer (score 0):

It may occur for inconsitent cache value of gradle daemon. You could kill all running gradle daemon manually and then run:

```
gradle clean build --refresh-dependencies
```

P.S.: I'm not entirely sure but deleting .gradle and reimporting project may fix it for IDEA.